# Programatically add multiple buttons to layout

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm currently adding buttons to my layout programatically into a linearLayout. This works great until my buttons extend past the width of the screen. Is there any way to get them to intelligently rollover to the next lines?

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

    tools:context=".MainActivity" >



    <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

        android:orientation="horizontal"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    </LinearLayout>



    <Button

        android:id="@+id/button1"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:onClick="doThis"

        android:text="Button" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

My onClick code:

```
public void doThis(View view){

Button myBtn = new Button(this);

LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);

myBtn.setText("hello");

layout.addView(myBtn);
}
```

This code works, but after the third button that is added, it starts to go off of the screen. Any advice would be appreciated.

After doThis runs 4 times:

[image]

After doThis runs 10 times:

[image]

Comment: There's a sample in Android SDK (you can access it through a common 4.0 virtual machine -> API Demos -> Animation) and look for it (I think it's called Custom Layouts or something like that). In that example you can see how buttons can be added and wrapped in a layout without bad stretchings. You should have a look

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayouts only expand in a single direction (in your case horizontal) so there is no way for it to "wrap" automatically. You could encapsulate it in a ScrollView if you wanted a scroll bar but then they will still be in a single row.

A better match for what you are doing is a GridView (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html). You provide a ListAdapter that populates it with entries that are organized into a grid.

There is a good GridView example available here: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/